# Answering own question and how it affects other Answerers

Tags: support

I want to be able to click Answer for someone who is helping me fine tune the answer he's been graciously working on/answering my questions. While he is doing that, I have just found an alternate answer. Can I answer my own question and click it as "AN" answer without the danger of the site forbidding me to click his as the answer, as well? In other words, I really want him to get credit for the answer, but mine is an alternate, albeit lame, answer.

Comment: You won’t be able to accept two answers, but you can accept their answer even when you yourself provide one.

Comment: @Pekka웃, thank you. Yes, I didn't think of that. I can just answer my own question by clicking the Answer My Own Question button, not tick it as the answer, but then tick his as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Pekka웃, I didn't know if you wanted to post your comment as an answer so I could mark it as an answer and upvote it as helpful. I'll check back a couple of times to see if you did so I can answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won’t be able to accept two answers.

However, you can upvote and accept their answer even when you yourself provide one.